# Modifying .bashrc to send history to syslog, problems with quotes

Tags: bash, ubuntu, bashrc

Attempting to enable logging of bash commands to syslog, including the ip of the logged in ssh user. The end goal is to have a script which will `echo 'export PROMPT_COMMAND=....'' >> ~/.bashrc`

This works if I manually edit .bashrc:

`export PROMPT_COMMAND='trap "" 1 2 15; history -a >(tee -a ~/.bash_history | while read line; do if [[ $line =~ ^#[0-9]*$ ]]; then continue; fi; logger -p local3.debug -t "bash[$$]" "($USER $SSH_CONNECTION) $line"; done); trap 1 2 15;'`

Adding `awk '{print $1}'` causes problems, I suspect because of quotes.

This doesn't work:

`export PROMPT_COMMAND='trap "" 1 2 15; history -a >(tee -a ~/.bash_history | while read line; do if [[ $line =~ ^#[0-9]*$ ]]; then continue; fi; logger -p local3.debug -t "bash[$$]" "($USER) $(echo $SSH_CONNECTION | awk '{print $1}') $line"; done); trap 1 2 15;'`

Attempting to wrap these quotes in the `echo 'export PROMPT_COMMAND=....'' >> ~/.bashrc` is also giving me a headache.

Any suggestions on both of these issues?

Comment: Why don't you write a shell function and call that from `PROMPT_COMMAND`?  Why do you `export PROMPT_COMMAND`?

Comment: @Kusalananda, I attempted to create a function as this seemed like the correct way to do this. Unfortunately ended up breaking bashrc and temporarily locking myself out of the VM. The single line command seemed easier.

Comment: Well, in that case, don't put single quotes inside a single quoted string (see the `awk` bit).  Doing it as a function would allow you to write readable code that doesn't have to use quoting tricks. It would also allow you to test it outside  of `PROMPT_COMMAND` before even setting that variable.